# Testing heat equation with $\log(u)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

On a bounded domain, let $u \in L^2\left(0,T;H^1\right) \cap H^1\left(0,T;H^{-1}\right)$ be weak solution to the heat equation 
$$u_t - \Delta u = 0$$
with the BC $\partial_\nu u = 0$ and some initial data, i.e.
$$\langle u_t, v \rangle + \int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla v = 0$$
holds for all $v \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$ for a.a. $t$.

Suppose we know that $u \geq 0$ a.e.

I want to test the equation with $\log(u)$. I don't think this is possible immediately since I can't show that $\nabla \log(u) = \frac{1}{u}\nabla u$ is in $L^2$. Is there some way to approximate this test function?

Comment: Why do you want to test the equation with $\log(u)$?

Comment: @gerw See this paper. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.2809.pdf. Here they have very weak solutions. But they derive (3.5) from (3.4) by differentiating in time and using the PDE (heat eq. with some BCs), so it amounts to testing with $\log u$.